# iTextSharp font widths definition not correctly loaded

Tags: pdf, text, itext, extract, itext7

I have peculiar issue with a PDF i got from a customer who used Ghostscript 9.19 to create a PDF/A compatible PDF (1.4). I want to extract text from it, using the LocationTextExtractionStrategy but I get most of the text in reversed order and with additional spaces:

expecting: abc

getting: c b a

in the content stream this might be [a,1,b,1,c] TJ

This issue has been posted to Stackoverflow before, however I cracked down the issue further than hacking my own extraction strategy. I realized that the font widths for the font used, is all zeroes and neither the metrics nor hMetrics maps are filled. I was using iTextSharp 5.5.4, but 5.5.9 still has the same issue.

This is the font:

```
/Subtype    /Type0  
/BaseFont   /VGOQEA+SegoeUI 
/Type   /Font   
/Encoding   33 0 R  
/ToUnicode  48 0 R  
/DescendantFonts    [35 0 R]
```

object 33 is a CMap:

```
/CIDSystemInfo  32 0 R  
/Filter /FlateDecode    
/Length 266 
/CMapName   /OneByteIdentityH   
/Type   /CMap
```

object 48 is a Stream and incidentally also a CMap

object 35 finally has some width definitions

```
/DW 539 
/CIDSystemInfo  32 0 R  
/Subtype    /CIDFontType2   
/BaseFont   /VGOQEA+SegoeUI 
/FontDescriptor 26 0 R  
/Type   /Font   
/W  [0, [646], 32, [274], 40, [302, 302], 44, [217, 400, 217], 48, [539, 539, 539, 539], 53, [539, 539, 539, 539], 58, [217], 64, [955, 645, 573], 68, [701, 506], 72, [710, 266], 75, [580, 471, 898], 80, [560], 82, [598, 531], 85, [687], 87, [934], 90, [570], 97, [509, 588, 462, 589, 523, 313, 589, 566, 242], 107, [497, 242, 861, 566, 586, 588], 114, [348, 424, 339, 566], 119, [723], 122, [452], 220, [687], 228, [509], 246, [586], 252, [566]]  
/CIDToGIDMap    47 0 R
```

In the order that iTextSharp initializes the CMapAwareDocumentFont, first the base DocumentFont gets initialized. The constructor then checks:

```
if (PdfName.TYPE1.Equals(subType) || PdfName.TRUETYPE.Equals(subType))
```

it's neither.

```
else if (PdfName.TYPE3.Equals(subType))
```

it's not. Then the next else branch is entered:

```
PdfName encodingName = font.GetAsName(PdfName.ENCODING);
if (encodingName == null)
```

but since encoding is given as an indirect reference, encodingName is null. Thusly the handling of this Type0 font is never handled.

I changed this bit in the library code, but even if the method ProcessType0(font) is called, the widths values never made it to the font definition - i.e. all remained zero. This is probably to be expected. Finally I got the metrics hash map filled, but i didn't cover all the used characters. I.e. the situation got a bit better, but not all good:

instead of: abc -> c b a

I now got: abc -> acb

My only working but hacky solution to the current issue was to hack processor.DisplayPdfString((PdfString)entryObj) to adjust the textMatrix by a fixed amount. However this is no general solution and I would rather that the font would work correctly. Any other suggestions what I should try?

EDIT:
I revisited my issue using iText 7 .Net and now I get a NullReferenceException when trying to read text from my test file.

```
var reader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(@"itextsharp_sample_locationtext_extraction_reversing_characters(1).pdf");
var extractionStrategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
var doc = new PdfDocument(reader);
var page = doc.GetFirstPage();
var test = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(doc.GetFirstPage());
Console.WriteLine(test);
```

This is the file I used: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1RdIg0_Pbd_aTlOT2VmbnFlaTQ/view?usp=sharing

The code works for other PDF files but not for this one.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to mkl I know now for a while that the underlying issue is font encoding streams. Sadly I just got a message via the iText sales team that this is not on the roadmap. They claim this is issue is a weird outlier, most anybody else does not need the support for font encoding streams. So if any of you reading this does have an issue with missing support, kindly let them know by email.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are extracting text in a language that's written left-to-right such as English?

Comment: yes, it's left-to-right. I finally managed to create an anonymized sample PDF, but I wonder where I should host this.

Comment: It is common to use a public dropbox or googledrive share.

Comment: thanks for the hint, mkl
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1RdIg0_Pbd_aTlOT2VmbnFlaTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, iText(Sharp) indeed still does not understand **Encoding** *streams* (in contrast to *names*) in composite fonts, neither in version 5.5.x nor in 7.0.x.

Comment: @mkl this is correct. I have added a ticket for this problem to the iText 7 backlog.